# TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment in numpy array for parallel loops

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, floating-point

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

df = pd.read_csv("/media/rahul/cd854f04-608f-4627-9e70-9096a8520b95/feature_bond/real_malware_v1/extracted_real_malware_v1.csv")
fields =[]
fields = list(df.columns)
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
#print(fields)
#print(len(fields))
n = len(fields)
n=n-1
    #print(len(fields))
mindvfij = np. empty((n,n), dtype='float64')
mindvfji = np. empty((n,n), dtype='float64')
print(mindvfij.dtype)
print(mindvfij.ndim)
print(mindvfij.shape)
    
print(df)
print(df.iloc[0,5])
x= df.iloc[0,5]
print(type(x))
print(len(df))
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        mindvfij = 0.0
        mindvfji = 0.0
def my_function(i,j):
    
    #print(j)
    nfij = 0
    nfi = 0
    nfj = 0
    for k in range(0, len(df)):
        x = df.iloc[k,i]
        y = df.iloc[k,j]
        if(x==1 and y==1):
            #print(nfij)
            nfij = nfij+1
                
            #print(nfij)
        if(x==1):
            nfi = nfi+1
        if(y==1):
            nfj = nfj+1
            #print("i is"+str(i)+"j is"+str(j)+"value is"+str(nfi) +":" + str(nfj) + ":" +str(nfij))
    if(nfi!=0):
        #print("i is:"+str(i)+"j is:"+str(j))
        a= nfij/nfi
        mindvfij[i-1,j-1]= a
 
    if(nfj!=0):
        #print("i is:"+str(i)+"j is:"+str(j))
        b = nfij/nfj
        mindvfji[i-1,j-1]= b
                
    if(nfi>0 and nfj>0):
        print("i is"+str(i)+"j is"+str(j)+"value is"+str(mindvfij[i-1,j-1]))
for i in range(1, len(fields)):
    print(i)
    Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(my_function)(i,j) for j in range(i+1, len(fields)))
np.save("/media/rahul/cd854f04-608f-4627-9e70-9096a8520b95/feature_bond/malindvfij",mindvfij)
np.save("/media/rahul/cd854f04-608f-4627-9e70-9096a8520b95/feature_bond/malindvfji",mindvfji)
print("Finish")
```

But getting error as
_RemoteTraceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rahul/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 436, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/home/rahul/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 288, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 595, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/.config/spyder-py3/untitled2.py", line 57, in my_function
TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment
"""


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/rahul/.config/spyder-py3/untitled2.py", line 63, in <module>
    Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(my_function)(i,j) for j in range(i+1, len(fields)))

  File "/home/rahul/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1056, in __call__
    self.retrieve()

  File "/home/rahul/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 935, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))

  File "/home/rahul/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 542, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)

  File "/home/rahul/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 445, in result
    return self.__get_result()

  File "/home/rahul/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
    raise self._exception

TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Do you know what`TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment` means? It's saying that you're trying to assign to an item of a float, but floats don't have items. Your problem is this: `mindvfij = 0.0` and `mindvfji = 0.0`, followed by `mindvfij[i-1,j-1]= a` and `mindvfji[i-1,j-1]= b`.

Comment: since i am updating mindvfij and mindvfji for those i and j for which my condition satisfies. that is why i initialize them to 0.0 so that no random value should not be there for rest of i and j. earlier i did not initialized then it picked 1e-45 for some of the i and j. Please suggest

Comment: Are you trying to initialize the values in an array named `mindvfij`? That's not what `mindvfij = 0.0` does; that line of code binds the name `mindvfij` to the float 0.0.  Maybe you want `mindvfij[i,j] = 0.0`? But then why not just use `np.zeros` instead of `np.empty`?

Comment: as per your suggestion i did set mindvfij = np. zeros((n,n), dtype='float64')
mindvfji = np. zeros((n,n), dtype='float64') but know i got the error as assignment destination is read-only

Comment: Was the line number for the error somewhere else in the code? I don't think a simple assignment statement binding a name to an object will raise that error.

Comment: yes line no was same. you can run on your machine and can check

Comment: So if you comment out everything after `mindvfij = np.zeros((n,n), dtype='float64')` and run your program, you get an error at that line?

Comment: no that is not the case

Comment: So that line is not the problem, and you need to debug your program to figure out which line is.